# Javascript/jquery error aDiv.children is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the relevant javascript

```
var DIV_ID = "agencyHoursTable";
function getAgencyHoursTable()
{
    var aDiv = document.getElementById(DIV_ID);
    return aDiv.children(0);
}
```

Here is the relevant jsp code

```
<table width=240 border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="agencyHoursTable">
                <table class="tblGrid" width=240 border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr id="header" class="subHeadingLeftNew">
                        <td class="subHeadingYellow" align=center><img src="../images/trash.gif"></td>
                        <td class="subHeadingYellow"><b>Day</b></td>
                        <td class="subHeadingYellow"><b>Time</b></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="RemoveSelectedLink" style="display:none">
                <a href='javascript:removeAgencyHours();' class="smallLink">Remove Selected</a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The error message that comes up is Uncaught TypeError: aDiv.children is not a function. I am thinking it is possible an issue with the jquery version, i am using jquery 1.7.1. The interesting thing is that for me the issue is only coming up in chrome, but not in ie. Some others using ie are seeing the issue, some others are not.

Answer (score 2):

you are not using jQuery at all.

```
var DIV_ID = "agencyHoursTable";
function getAgencyHoursTable()
{
    var aDiv = document.getElementById(DIV_ID);
    return aDiv.children[0];
}
```

You can reach the element through css selector:

```
jQuery("#agencyHoursTable > table");
```